# Saving variable types under a single key in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

I have bunch of documents coming in from [fluentd](http://fluentd.org/) and I'm saving then to elasticsearch with [fluent-plugin-elasticsearch](https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch).

Some of those documents have a string under the key `name` and some have an object.

Example

```
{
  "name": "foo"
}
```

and

```
{
  "name": {
    "en": "foo",
    "fi": "bar"  
  }
}
```

These documents are the same type in terms of my application and they are saved to same elasticsearch index.

But elasticsearch has an issue with this. When the second document is saved to elasticsearch it throws this error:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [name]
```

This seems to happen because elasticsearch has set the key `name` to be type of string. I can see this using `curl http://localhost:9200/fluentd-[tagname]/_mapping` and it obviously doesn't like it when I try save an object to it afterwards.

So is there any way to workaround this in elasticsearch?

I cannot control the incoming documents and there are multiple keys with variable types - not just `name`. So I cannot make a single hack for that key only.

This is pretty annoying since those documents are completely left out of elasticsearch and sent to /dev/null.

If this is completely impossible - is possible to at least save those documents to a file or something so I wouldn't lose them?

Here's my template for the `fluentd-*` indices:

```
{
  "fluentd_template": {
    "template": "fluentd-*",
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0,
      "index": {
        "query": {
          "default_field": "msg"
        },
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "default" : {
                    "type" : "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_default_": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "_source": {
          "compress": true
        },
        "properties": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it is not possible..

Comment: There is no way to work around this as this how Lucene works under the hood. This means you can't mix string types and nested types for the same field name. Can you not make the first instance into a nested type also?

Comment: @GarryWelding I guess I have to then...